# Amazon device farm - @Tests are not executing in order

Tags: amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

I have used @Tests(priority=1) etc,. but tests are not executing in order.
New session is created for every @Test method in amazon device farm.
 Following is the log message [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA

Answer (score 1):

AWS Device Farm does not currently support test ordering, this is a know issue and in our backlog.